# Display Multiple Non Empty Dataframes on HTML Email

Tags: python, html, pandas

I'm trying to display multiple dataframes in the body of an email to end users. There are 100 end users and each df is filtered to display only their entries. Some dataframes could be empty, depending on the records created by the end user. My code looks like this:

```
email_body = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
        <br>{Coa_df}<br>
        <br>{IA_df}<br>  
        <br>{Part_df}<br>  
        <br>{PA_df}<br>  
        <br>{PSE_df}<br> 
  </body>
</html>
"""

new_email_body = email_body.format(Coa_df = '<h1> Coalitions </h1>' + Coa_df.to_html(),
                       IA_df = '<h1> Indirect Activities </h1>' + IA_df.to_html(),
                       Part_df = '<h1> Partnerships </h1>' + Part_df.to_html(),
                       PA_df = '<h1> Program Activities </h1>' + PA_df.to_html(),
                       PSE_df = '<h1> PSE Site Activities </h1>' + PSE_df.to_html())
```

However, this will display every dataframe whether or not they're empty.

To exclusively display non-empty dataframes, I've created a dict of dfs to run through a for loop. However, I'm not sure how to display more than one dataframe this way. Here's what I've got:

```
email_body = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
        <br>{df1}<br>
  </body>
</html>
"""
dfs = {'Coalitions' : Coa_df, 'Indirect Activities' : IA_df, 'Partnerships' : Part_df, 'Program Activities' : PA_df, 'PSE Site Activities' : PSE_df}
for heading, df in dfs.items():
     if df.empty == False:
            new_email_body = email_body.(staff_name = staff_name, deadline_date = deadline_date, df1 = '<h1> ' + heading + ' </h1>' + df.to_html())
```

This only displays the last non-empty df in the html. My attempts to display every non-empty df result in errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've got a solution. I've set the curly brackets in the email body to reference index numbers.

```
email_body = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
        <br>{0}<br>
        <br>{1}<br>  
        <br>{2}<br>  
        <br>{3}<br>  
        <br>{4}<br> 
  </body>
</html>
"""
```

I then define x for the input arguments of `.format()` and loop through dfs to append to x.

```
dfs = {'Coalitions' : Coa_df, 'Indirect Activities' : IA_df, 'Partnerships' : Part_df, 'Program Activities' : PA_df, 'PSE Site Activities' : PSE_df}

x = []

for heading, df in dfs.items():
    if df.empty == False:
            x.append('<h1> ' + heading + ' </h1>' + df.to_html(border=2, justify='center'))
    else:
        x.append('')
```

Finally, I format the input arguments to the email body.

```
new_email_body = email_body.format(*x)
```

This method seems to work well enough, but I'd appreciate any feedback.